# Visual studio shows Error window without any error in error list BLAZOR after converting project from .net 5 to dot net 6

Tags: blazor

After I upgraded my Blazor project from .NET version 5 to .NET 6 version, a Visual Studio error box message appears during execution, but interestingly, no error is displayed in the Visual Studio error list. (Following picture)

[image]

After clicking on No, a series of warnings will be displayed only in the list of errors.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0414  The field 'AgentRequest.isProsses' is assigned but its value is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Agent\AgentRequest.razor   684 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'AgentRequestEdit.ImageFile' is assigned but its value is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Agent\AgentRequestEdit.razor   530 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'AgentRequestStep.isProsses' is assigned but its value is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Agent\AgentRequestStep.razor   682 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'BillationReceiptDetail._panel5' is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\BillationReceipt\BillationReceiptDetail.razor  117 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'ChangeStatusComponent.int_BillationID_Privete' is assigned but its value is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\ChangeStatusComponent.razor    57  Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'InstallNeedComponent.int_BillationID_Privete' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\InstallNeedComponent.razor 109 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'InstallNeedComponent.BillationReceiptInstallRequiredMps' is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\InstallNeedComponent.razor 124 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'BillationReceiptComponent.Message7' is assigned but its value is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\BillationReceiptComponent.razor    497 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'BillationReceiptComponent.ImageBase64' is never used CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\BillationReceiptComponent.razor    566 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'BillationReceiptComponent.inputElement' is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\BillationReceiptComponent.razor    568 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'BillationReceiptComponent.Message' is assigned but its value is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\BillationReceiptComponent.razor    613 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'BillationReceiptComponent.selectedFiles' is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Component\BillationReceiptComponent.razor    614 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CreateBillation.isProsses' is assigned but its value is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CreateBillation.razor    411 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CreateBillation.IsShowAccept' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CreateBillation.razor    412 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CreateBillation.BlnLastStandShow' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CreateBillation.razor    415 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CreateBillation.ShowSmsPanel' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CreateBillation.razor    425 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CreateBillation.HidePrevButton' is assigned but its value is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CreateBillation.razor    426 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'CustomerUpload.ImageUrl' is assigned but its value is never used CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CustomerUpload.razor 115 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'CustomerUpload1.ImageUrl' is never used  CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\CustomerUpload1.razor    30  Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'Billationlist.StatusClass' is assigned but its value is never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Billationlist.razor  391 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'Billationlist.ReferenceToInputControl' is never used CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\Billationlist.razor  393 Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'UploadForm.itm' is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Pages\Billation\UploadForm.razor 40  Active
Warning CS0169  The field 'AgentRepository.httpClient' is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Repositories\AgentRepository.cs  45  Active
Warning CS0168  The variable 'ex' is declared but never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Repositories\AgentRepository.cs  144 Active
Warning CS0168  The variable 'ex' is declared but never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Repositories\AgentRepository.cs  279 Active
Warning CS0168  The variable 'exx' is declared but never used   CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Repositories\ReciptionRepository.cs  667 Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'DateShamsiComponent.StatusClass' is assigned but its value is never used CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Shared\DateShamsiComponent.razor 18  Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'InputImageFromFile.BlnUserParamImage' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Shared\InputImageFromFile.razor  67  Active
Warning CS0414  The field 'TreeViewGoodsComponent.str_m' is assigned but its value is never used    CrmWeb.Client   D:\Projects\CRM\Client\Shared\TreeViewGoodsComponent.razor  500 Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Controllers\AgentController.cs   234 Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\IAgent.cs   635 Active
Warning CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'double' is never equal to 'null' of type 'double?'    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\IBalance.cs 102 Active
Warning CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'decimal' is never equal to 'null' of type 'decimal?'  CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\IPartyBallance.cs   67  Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\IValuation.cs   90  Active
Warning CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'  CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    573 Active
Warning CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'  CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    574 Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    753 Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    1178    Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    1211    Active
Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    1711    Active
Warning CS0168  The variable 'ex' is declared but never used    CrmWeb.Server   D:\Projects\CRM\Server\Repositories\Billation.cs    1905    Active
```

And you can see the picture as bellow:

[image]

In addition, it should be mentioned that I have updated all the installed components of the project from lower versions to the latest versions. In the client Layer:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>-->
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.Modal" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.Toast" Version="3.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Collapse" Version="1.5.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.6" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol" Version="16.9.50204.1" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="PersianDatePicker" Version="1.1.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />-->
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="5.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Tewr.Blazor.FileReader" Version="3.3.1.21360" />

      <PackageReference Include="Blazor.PersianDatePicker" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\CrmWeb.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

In the Server Layer:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <DisableImplicitComponentsAnalyzers>true</DisableImplicitComponentsAnalyzers>
    <!--<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>-->

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <Compile Remove="Entity\**" />
    <Content Remove="Entity\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Entity\**" />
    <None Remove="Entity\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="DbContext\CrmWebContextold.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Sender\SendSms.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Blazored.Modal" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.Toast" Version="3.1.2" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.5.4" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="MD.PersianDateTime.Core" Version="2.3.5" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <!--Log4Net-->
    <PackageReference Include="MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <!--end Log4Net-->

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol" Version="17.2.60629.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.17.4" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="PersianDatePicker" Version="1.1.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Tewr.Blazor.FileReader" Version="3.3.1.21360" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\CrmWeb.Client.csproj">
      <CopyLocal>True</CopyLocal>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\CrmWeb.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Connected Services\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\Files\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In addition, most of the methods available on the Internet and the Stackoverflow website do not check either, but I have not received an answer.
If you have a solution for this problem, please help. thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Did you try to build the project? It must show a list of error

Comment: @Mohammed Alwedaei Thanks for your reply. in you answer I should say yes. I Build an Re-Build many times. But unfortunately I got same error.

Comment: In the output window, there must be a log about the build. have a look at it

Comment: Mr. @Mohammed Alwedaei I watched to the Build part. But all of projects builds ok and without any error. 
`1>Done building project "CrmWeb.Shared.csproj".`
`2>Done building project "CrmWeb.Client.csproj".`
`3>Done building project "CrmWeb.Server.csproj".`
`========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`
I just get error when I want to run my website in VS 2022 and I updated to the latest version of VS 2022 but it could not help me to solve my problem.

Comment: In the first and third picture is a dropdown with `Build + Intellisense`, if you switch that to `Build only` you still see no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Errors window is not always reliable.

You should be able to see the build errors in the Output window:

[image]

Alternatively, run `dotnet build` command in the project folder and you should see the errors as well

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Liero based on your suggestion I watched to the Build part. But all of projects builds ok and without any error. 
`1>Done building project "CrmWeb.Shared.csproj".`
`2>Done building project "CrmWeb.Client.csproj".`
`3>Done building project "CrmWeb.Server.csproj".`
`========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`
I just get error when I want to run my website in VS 2022 and I updated to the latest version of VS 2022 but it could not help me to solve my problem.